# NServiceBus cannot find Endpoint or MessageEndpointMappings in unobtrusive mode

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, nservicebus, nservicebus5

I am trying to hook up a primitive `TestService` endpoint to a primitive WCF service, where the WCF service instance sends a primitive `TestCommand` to the `TestService` endpoint, using latest NSB 5.2.9/Host6.0:

```
[ServiceBehavior(
    InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall,
    ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single )]
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private readonly IBus bus;

    public MyService( IBus bus )
    {
        this.bus = bus;
    }

    public void Test( string value )
    {
        bus.Send( new TestCommand( value ) );
    }
}
```

I am unable to configure this correctly. Error message:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.ServiceModel.dll

Additional information: No destination could be found for message type Company.App.Commands.TestCommand. Check the <**MessageEndpointMappings**> section of the configuration of this endpoint for an entry either for this specific message type or for its assembly.
```

**I am able to do this without using the "unobtrusive node", but not with conventions. I am  very confused as to how to configure this after I tried everything.
The WCF Host is self hosted, while the Test endpoint is hosted by NServiceBus.Host.**

1. web.config of the IIS WCF Host application
2. via NServiceBus.Config.IConfigurationSource
3. via NServiceBus.Config.IProvideConfiguration

Right now I have this in the web.config, which is seemignly useless and ignored:

```
<MessageEndpointMappings>
    <add Assembly="Company.App.Messages" Type="Company.App.Commands.TestCommand" Endpoint="testservice" />
</MessageEndpointMappings>
```

**"Unobtrusive mode":** I have created a separate project for conventions, which is referenced by the WCF host endpoint and the TestService endpoint.

```
public class MessageConventions : INeedInitialization
{
    public void Customize( BusConfiguration configuration )
    {
        var conventions = configuration.Conventions();

        conventions.DefiningCommandsAs( t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.StartsWith( "Company.App" ) && t.Namespace.EndsWith( "Commands" ) );
        conventions.DefiningEventsAs( t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.StartsWith( "Company.App" ) && t.Namespace.EndsWith( "Events" ) );
        conventions.DefiningMessagesAs( t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.StartsWith( "Company.App" ) );

        //conventions.DefiningTimeToBeReceivedAs( t => GetTimeToBeReceived( t ) )
        //conventions.DefiningDataBusPropertiesAs( pi => IsDataBusProperty( pi ) );
    }
}
```

These conventions are seemingly picked up by `TestService`.

My understanding is that the IIS WCF Host must declare the mappings in its web.config, so that the WCF service knows where to send the messages with `bus.Send(new TestCommand("test"));` but this does not work.

Then I tried defining these mappings in both endpoints, but no luck.

This method will output all message types that where found using the conventions above:

```
public class Startup : IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops
{
public MessageMetadataRegistry Messages { get; set; }
public Conventions Conventions { get; set; }

public void Start()
{
    var getAllMessagesMethod = typeof( MessageMetadataRegistry ).GetMethod( "GetAllMessages",
        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance );

    var allMessages = getAllMessagesMethod.Invoke( Messages, new object[ 0 ] ) as IEnumerable<MessageMetadata>;

    foreach ( var metadata in allMessages )
    {
        Type type = metadata.MessageType;
        string name = type.FullName;

        if ( this.Conventions.IsInSystemConventionList( type ) )
            Console.WriteLine( "System Msg: {0}", name );
        else if ( this.Conventions.IsCommandType( type ) )
            Console.WriteLine( "   Command: {0}", name );
        else if ( this.Conventions.IsEventType( type ) )
            Console.WriteLine( "     Event: {0}", name );
        else if ( this.Conventions.IsMessageType( type ) )
            Console.WriteLine( "   Message: {0}", name );

        if ( metadata.TimeToBeReceived != TimeSpan.MaxValue )
            Console.WriteLine( "            TimeToBeReceived={0}", metadata.TimeToBeReceived );
    }
}

public void Stop()
{
}
}
```

Above method outputs the message type "TestCommand", so it knows about the conventions made.

I already checked 1000x for typos, casing, everyhting. I cleaned the solution.
**My question is: why can't NServiceBus find the endpoint?**

Please help.

Comment: Can you post your mappings from the web.config?

Comment: @TylerDay thanks, I updated my question. The thing to remember is, I tried to configure this with and WTIHOUT the web.config, using IConfigurationSource and IProvideConfiguration. None of these work. Thanks!

Comment: Your webconfig maps a command named "RunTestCommand", not "TestCommand" as your sample code shows.

Comment: @TylerDay that wasn't it.Just a type while annonymizing the code above. Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Unobtrusive means that you tell NServiceBus which classes are command and events by conventions rather than implementing the marker interfaces, you still need to add a message mapping in the app/web config so that NServiceBus knows which queue to send the message to.

The exception is suggesting that is your problem

```
Check the <**MessageEndpointMappings**> section of the configuration of this endpoint for an entry either for this specific message type or for its assembly.
```

Make sure you still have something like this in your web.config:

```
<UnicastBusConfig>
  <MessageEndpointMappings>
    <add Messages="Company.App.Commands.TestCommand, Company.App.Commands" Endpoint="test.server" />
  </MessageEndpointMappings>
</UnicastBusConfig>
```

EDIT

Now that you have posted your web.config, the problem looks like you have the wrong type name in the web.config:

```
<add Assembly="Company.App.Messages" Type="Company.App.Commands.RunTestCommand"
```

but you're doing this `bus.Send(new TestCommand(value));`

So the web.config is wrong, it should be

```
<add Assembly="Company.App.Messages" Type="Company.App.Commands.TestCommand"
```

Comment: thanks, but I have all that in the web.config. I don't think the config attribute you used is correct: Messages="...", shouldn't this be Assembly="..." ?

Comment: It might have changed slightly, I'm not using NSB 5 yet.

Comment: you were right, Messages can be used, still, as well as Assembly.